# How to mock script invocation with Pester?

Tags: windows, powershell, pester

I want to create a mock with Pester which is supposed to be called in stead of a script.
Simplified example below.

**somecmd.ps1**

```
# This is the script I want to not be called in my test.

Write-Host "Output from somecmd.ps1"
throw "Error, should have been mocked"
```

**somemodule.psm1**

```
# This is the module I am testing.

function ModuleFunction{
    .\somecmd
}

function somecmd {
    Write-Host "Output from somecmd in somemodule"
    throw "Error, should never be called"
}
```

**somemodule.Tests.ps1**

```
# This is my Pester test.

BeforeAll {
    Import-Module .\somemodule.psm1 -Force
}

Describe 'SomeTest' {
    It 'Should mock' {
        # How must I declare the mock below so that somecmd.ps1 is not invoked?
        Mock somecmd { Write-Host "Output from mock" } -ModuleName somemodule
        ModuleFunction
    }
}
```

As stated in the comment above, my problem is I cannot figure out how to declare the mock, so that the test will use that in stead of actually invoking somecmd.ps1.

I tried looking into [this issue](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/406), but following the suggestion there did not solve my problem.

Unfortunately, in my real scenario, it is not an option for me to re-write the module to better support testing.

I am running:

- PowerShell: 5.1.19041.1682
- Pester: 5.3.3

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

From the GitHub Issue you linked, I don't think you can mock a *.ps1 script directly.

However, a simple workaround is to wrap your call to `.\somecmd.ps1` in a separate function, and then mock that...

**somemodule.psm1**

```
function Invoke-SomeCmd
{
    .\somecmd
}

function ModuleFunction{
    # do some stuff
    Invoke-SomeCmd
    # do some more stuff
}
```

**somemodule.Tests.ps1**

```
BeforeAll {
    Import-Module .\somemodule.psm1 -Force
}

Describe 'SomeTest' {
    It 'Should mock' {
        Mock "Invoke-SomeCmd" {
            Write-Host "Output from mock"
        } -ModuleName somemodule
        ModuleFunction
    }
}
```

and then you get this output:

```
Starting discovery in 1 files.
Discovery found 1 tests in 327ms.
Running tests.
Output from mock
[+] C:\src\so\pester\somemodule.tests.ps1 992ms (274ms|433ms)
Tests completed in 1.02s
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yeah, I know that would be an option. However, the module is not one that I have control over, so I cannot do the wrapping. I probably should have stated this explicitly. I know my example is simplified, cause in a real scenario I would only create tests for my own modules.

Comment: I'm not sure you *can* in that case. The GitHub Issue you linked to alludes to that, and in my testing I got two different errors depending on whether I mocked the correct path to the *.ps1 or not, but both caused errors in the actual tests.